# If devkit has been installed, then how to uninstall?

Tags: ruby

How to uninstall [Ruby's development kit on windows](https://github.com/OneClick/RubyInstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)? I have to re-install ruby, because its installation path contained a space.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to delete it if you're just going to reinstall it and Ruby; just reinstall Ruby and then, in a Command Prompt window, `cd` into the DevKit directory and run `ruby dk.rb init`.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to uninstall it properly, if you don't want to reinstall ? Is it safe to just delete the devkit folder ?

Answer (score 1):

From the link you posted.

> •If you previously installed the legacy DevKit
>   devkit-3.4.5r3-20091110.7z, its artifacts were extracted into each
>   Ruby installation and need to be manually removed. Remove the gcc.bat,
>   make.bat, and sh.bat stub batch files in \bin and
>   the \devkit subdirectory for each Ruby installation
>   using the legacy DevKit.
>
> •If you previously installed one of the
>   legacy self-extracting DevKit’s, follow the SFX DevKit upgrade
>   instructions.

The SFX upgrade instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#wiki-upgrade_dk).